# How to get Image Uri

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I captured an image in my Windows Phone app and copied it to an image from canvas by making stream. Now i want to get its Uri to merge it with another image. This is what i have done so far

XAML:

```
<Canvas x:Name="frontCanvas" Margin="373,0,0,0" Grid.RowSpan="2">            
    <Canvas.Background>
        <VideoBrush x:Name="frontBrush" >
            <VideoBrush.RelativeTransform>
                <CompositeTransform x:Name="viewCompositeTransform" 
                  ScaleX="-1" CenterX=".5" CenterY=".5"/>
            </VideoBrush.RelativeTransform>
        </VideoBrush>
    </Canvas.Background>
</Canvas>

<Image Visibility="Collapsed" x:Name="frontImage" Margin="373,0,0,0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
</Image>
```

C#

```
void frontCam_CaptureImageAvailable(
      object sender, Microsoft.Devices.ContentReadyEventArgs e)
{ 
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        BitmapImage bmp2 = new BitmapImage();
        bmp2.SetSource(e.ImageStream);
        frontImage.Source = bmp2;
        frontCanvas.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        frontImage.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        //img2Name = bmp2.UriSource.ToString();
     });
}
```

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssehgal/archive/2012/02/03/windows-phone-code-sample-capturing-image-from-camera-and-updating-live-tile.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i do not want to store it. I want to merge it before  i store it.I just need its Uri is there any way to get it.

Comment: Side note: when editing post/approving edits please avoid using "code" quotes for highlighting and misuse other formatting features (i.e. using quotes ">" for getting yellow background). Also try to format your code to fit on screen without scrolling. (@smoother-sillent - please check http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308047/is-using-backticks-for-inline-quotes-acceptable/308050#308050 on usage of back-ticks).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I put in my mind and I take care for it in future thanks

Comment: will not happen again thanks @Alexei Levenkov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the image displayed in an `Image` that was captured from the camera then it won't have a URI. You'll have to work with it as a stream (or similar).

For combining images look at the blitting functions in the [WriteableBitmapEx](https://github.com/teichgraf/WriteableBitmapEx/) library.
Alternatively, if you're just looking to add effects to your image try the [Lumia Imaging SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt598502.aspx).